# any tools for importing multiple file versions into git?

Tags: git, git-fast-import

I somewhat-frequently get myself in the following situation:

I start on what's supposed to be a "small project" (pretty much always a one file script), and decide the project is simple enough that I don't need to version control it with git.

So I work on the script - call it `do-thing.py`.
At some point, I decide I want to do some refactoring, or make some other large change. I decide to make a backup in case it doesn't work out and I want to revert. So, I copy the file and name the copy something like `do-thing 1-before big refactor.py`.

This goes on, and at some point, I have a folder filled with various old snapshots of the script:

```
do-thing.py
do-thing 1-before big refactor.py
do-thing 2-before changed function.py
do-thing 3-before alg change.py
```

where the order from oldest to newest is `do-thing 1-*.py`, `do-thing 2-*.py`, `do-thing 3-*.py`, `do-thing.py` (although this detail isn't critical to this question).

At this point (with perhaps even more than 3 backups), I realized this project was bigger than expected, and I should have just used version control to begin with. Unfortunately, this realization only comes after I wind up in this situation.

I'd like to convert a series of files like this into a series of git commits. I've done this in the past manually, but wanted to know if there's any existing tooling for it. ideally, it would also use the filename as the commit message.

Are there any existing tools for converting file versions into a git history?

In the git pro book, in [this section](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git), there's this quote: *"quality importers are available for many other systems, ...even a directory of archives."*, suggesting tooling like this exists, but they don't give any references.

In the same section, near the bottom, they give an example script that does this for folders. I was considering just writing my own git fast-exporter for this use case, but I figured this use case must be very common, so I wanted to see about existing options before writing my own.

I wasn't able to find anything online, so I'm asking here. Are you aware of any tools to do this conversion?

Comment: `git fast-import` is the (usual, at least) Git side of the import process; it reads a text stream (or mostly-text-with-binary-in-it-if/as-needed) from its standard input. Other exporters write this same text format so that you can pipe them into `git fast-import`.

Comment: (This isn't an answer, because it's mostly just re-stating the same stuff at the end of that chapter of the Pro Git book. Look for *-fast-export names though, if you're searching for existing exporters.)

Comment: hello again, lol. yes, i'm familiar with fast-import. the git book made it seem like there were existing tools that output the fast-import spec from a selection of files like this. that is what i was after.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an existing tool, but I would make a simple script which would:

- create an empty repo
- for each work iteration

  - create a "iteration-x" folder
  - copy the do-thing-x files
  - [add only new or modified files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---no-all) from that folder to the new repo

That is, for each iteration:

```sh
cd /path/to/new/repo
git --work-tree=/path/to/do-thing-x add --ignore-removal .
git commit -m "Import iteration x"
```

As commented, for just one file, that is overkill and slow.
[`git fast-import`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import) is certainly easier.

Comment: this sounds like it works in the more general case of having multiple snapshots as folders, as discussed in the git book chapter i linked. in my case however, the script could be simpler, as the only thing that changes version to version is that single `do-thing.py` file

Comment: I agree. The same general idea would apply though, but for one file.

Comment: This is a super minor thing, but your script is using the standard git commands, e.g. `git commit`. this is fine, but if there were a lot of revisions, it might be pretty slow, compared to a [`git fast-export`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import) approach. this is kind of an unnecessary point to make however, as this script probably wouldn't see more than 10 revisions at most. just wanted to mention it in case someone got this idea but had a ton of revisions to parse. then again, you only need to run it once anyway, so maybe speed isn't an issue.